# Why are these algebraic manipulations needed to conclude this fixed point theorem?

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

In [Evasiveness of Graph Properties and Topological Fixed Point Theorems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.0110v2.pdf) on page 46 it states that (where $F$ is the associated chain map for any function $f$):

$$Tr_F(H_0(\Delta, F_p)) = 1$$

Because $F$ acts "trivially" on $H_0$.

Later (on the same page) it mentions, as, in this case, $f$ is an automorphism that the matrix $F$ has zeros on the diagnol, and hence, the trace is always zero. So:

$$Tr_F(H_n(\Delta, F_p)) = 0$$ for $n \geq 0$.

The paper then proceeds to give this long complicated series of summation/algebraic manipulations to show that $0$ does not in fact equal $1$. Why is it not already a contradiction to note that the trace is always $1$ (because $F$ acts trivially) and simutanteously $0$ because $f$ being an automorphism implies a zero trace for $H_0$?

Comment: @EricWofsey: In the paper it says in the paper that only zeros can be contained in the diagonal because $f$ is an automorphism. So that would imply the trace is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing two different actions of $f$.  The reason that $Tr_F(H_n(\Delta, \mathbb{F}_p)) = 0$ for $n>0$ is *not* that the matrix has zeroes on the diagonal; it's simply that $H_n(\Delta, \mathbb{F}_p)=0$ so you are taking the trace of a $0\times 0$ matrix.  This argument only applies for $n>0$, since $H_0(\Delta,\mathbb{F}_p)$ is not trivial.

The matrix which has zeroes on the diagonal is the action of $f$ on $K_n(\Delta,\mathbb{F}_p)$: that is, on the chains, not the homology.  This is because we are assuming $f$ fixes no simplices (*not* because $f$ is an automorphism), and a basis for the chains is given by the simplices.  This does *not* apply to the action of $f$ on homology, and in particular does not tell you that $Tr_F(H_0(\Delta, \mathbb{F}_p))$ should be $0$.

Comment: Oh. I thought everything was $H$. Thank you.